# How to put all elements of a String array into Queue(Of String)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I want to put all elements of a String array into a Queue(Of String). I have following code which using **For...Each** to put string into Queue(Of String):

```
    Dim Files() As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
    'OpenFileDialog1 is an instance of OpenFileDialog control

    Dim PendingFiles As New Queue(Of String)

    For Each x1 As String In Files
        PendingFiles.Enqueue(x1)
    Next
```

My question: Is that possible to do it (i.e. put **string array** into **Queue(Of String)**) without using **For...Each**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the constructor of [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69zckb8z.aspx) that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
Dim PendingFiles As New Queue(Of String)(Files)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the constructor of `Queue` iterates over the collection parameter and calls `Enqueue` on each item. Using this constructor overload won't perform any better and it does have the slight downside that it reduces readability of your code.

Comment: @Jason - Yes, reduces. Before I could tell that the files were being enqueued just by looking at the code. Afterwards I have to have knowledge of the constructor of `Queue` to "read" the code - someone not familiar with `Queue` might need to look up the documentation to know what it was doing.

Comment: @Enigmativity: If I see a generic collection parameterized by ` T` that has a constructor that accepts a sequence of `T` (`IEnumerable<T>`), it's intuitively obvious to me that this constructor is going to initialize the collection with the sequence. This version of the code more clearly expresses the intent (initialize the queue with a sequence of file names) without worrying about the mechanism (`foreach`).

Comment: @Jason - Absolutely. For experienced developers the intent is clear. My comment relates to helping less experienced coders by making the code more explicit.